# How to create a variable in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to create an animation of an object (eg: Ico Sphere) moving in an integer grid on the XY-plane. The Ico Sphere starts at the origin.

At each frame (a very slow FPS so we can track the move), it moves 1 unit in the positive X- or Y-direction; with a probability of about 40%-60%.

When the animation stops after 100 frames, I want to do something with the value (eg: the number of times in X-direction and may be some other things). The simplest thing is to render the values as a text object, or color them depending on the value.

My question is how can I create a variable to store these values so I can update them at each frame and retrieve them later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, your wish cannot be fulfilled with *Geometry Nodes*.

At least not the way you thought, because there are no variables or loops in *Geometry Nodes* as known from programming...

---

But there is another way:

You could just calculate the probability in advance.

The result would look like this:

[image]

The principle behind this is that you create a curve of a certain number of points. For each point you randomly set a boolean value. This way you have the same information for all frames and can build the nodes accordingly:

[image]

- First I slow down the time by decreasing the current frame with a factor.
- Then I create a curve with a certain number of points.
- These points get a boolean value with a certain probability. The node `Random Value` helps with this. If this value is $1$, then later a step will be added on the *X-axis*. If the value is $0$, then a step will be added on the *Y-axis*.
- Next, I delete all points from the curve that are above the current (slowed down) frame.
- The remaining points then provide me with their previously assigned boolean value, which I accumulate.
- The accumulated value now gives me all the steps on the *X-axis*, and if I subtract this value from the current frame, I get the number of steps on the *Y-axis*. These values are then combined in a vector and captured in the geometry.
- Finally, this value only needs to be transferred, and on the one hand used directly as a position for the object to be moved, and on the other hand as a numerical value for the numbers to be created.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks @quellenform for the details and the demo file!

Comment: @Shung-Ching You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You could use *Accumulate Field* for this job.

This cluster will generate a curve of random positive X and Y unit-segments, growing over time:

[image]

The growth is achieved by resampling an arbitrary curve as a multiple of frame-count. Its points are then located at an accumulation of randomly-selected (1,0,0) and (0,1,0) vectors, starting from the origin.

Then something can be instanced on the curve's endpoint, and/or a grid added to match:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Haha, funny, once again I was thinking a bit complicated. :D Instead of shortening the curve, it can of course be "lengthened". +1 ...I think I'm slowly becoming routine-blinded

Comment: @quellenform   I liked the thinking behind yours (+1).. but I think you owe me a drink at the 19th hole ; )

Comment: Ahh, but I just noticed that should be integer-random 0/1. another node gone.. :D

Comment: Thanks @RobinBetts for the explanation and the demo file!